# PDF file damaged after upload but local copy is fine. How could this be happening?

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file which I am uploading to my server. I can open the local version through my browser and it opens fine, but when I upload it to the server and try to open it directly through there then I get a:

> The file is damaged and could not be repaired message.

Likewise, if I download one of the many pdf's on my server to my local computer, then there is always now some error in opening them or they are blank.

I am using FileZilla to upload and download the files by ftp.

This situation has only just started and I'm not sure why. I have a backup directory of the pdf's and have copied and replaced all the files with the backups in an effort to fix the issue. I am now able to type the file location into the address bar and view them like that which is an improvement, but if I try and download them, then I get some sort of error which means I can't view them.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting FileZilla's file transfer mode to `binary` and **not** `ASCII` seems to have done the trick.