# I/O error opening pdf after uploading to ftp

Tags: c#, pdf, ftpwebrequest, ioerror

So Im trying to upload a file to my ftp server. Every things seems to work like expected but when I open the file from from the ftp I receive a I/O error. The local file works just fine. Some how the file gets corrupt after uploading. I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415295/pdf-file-damaged-after-upload-but-local-copy-is-fine-how-could-this-be-happenin).

Here I read that you have to change the transfer mode to binary. I tried to set `ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;` But I still get the I/O error. Do I have to change the transfer mode somewhere els?

**This is my ftp upload code:**

```
public string upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(localFile);
    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());

    sourceStream.Close();
    ftpRequest.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
    Stream requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();

    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
    return string.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
}
```

Using webclient I get the error:

> The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed.

**Here is my code:**

```
private void uploadToPDF(int fileName, string localFilePath, string ftpPath, string baseAddress)
{
    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    webclient.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
    webclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

    webclient.UploadFile(ftpPath + fileName + ".pdf", localFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Did you see this question/answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9738609/1346943

Comment: @ledbutter When I upload the file with using the webclient I get the message "The remote server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed."

Comment: What is the File Name?

Comment: Especially, what is `ftpPath + fileName + ".pdf"`?

Comment: @mkl somting like ftp://192.168.1.1/home/187520.pdf

Comment: Have you tried with `ftp://` in front of that? UploadFile expects an URI.

Comment: @mkl It has ftp:// in front of it but if I type it here its removed because its a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `upload` most likely breaks the PDF contents because it treats it as text:

You use a `StreamReader` to read the PDF file. That class

> Implements a TextReader that reads characters from a byte stream in a particular encoding.
>
> *([MSDN StreamReader information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))*

This implies that while reading the file bytes, the class interprets them according to that *particular encoding* (UTF-8 in your case because that's the default). But not all byte combinations do make sense as UTF-8 character combinations. Thus, this reading already is destructive.

You partially make up for this interpretation by re-encoding the characters according to UTF-8 later:

```
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
```

but as said before, the initial interpretation, the decoding as a UTF-8 encoded file already has destroyed the original file unless you were lucky enough and all the byte combinations made sense as UTF-8 encoded text.

For binary data (like ZIP archives, Word documents or PDF files) you should use the `FileStream` class, cf. [its MSDN information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok great I got it to work with FileStream! Thanks for the info :)